# When does the Android Eclipse toolkit run lint?

Tags: android, lint

I just worked through the [first introductory application](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) for Android programming and noticed some strange behavior:

When the second Activity was generated it received the line:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

in the onCreate function. As the tutorial points out, this line requires at least API level 11 and a guard for that and @SuppressLint("NewApi") should be added like so:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

The strange thing is that ignoring this advice and just hitting run worked fine at first but as soon as I made changes to the code it didn't work anymore and I got errors.

So when is lint actually active?

Comment: What were the changes you made in the code?